# How to avoid error in the output (render) of a reactive object that will still be created in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, r-package

I'm not able to solve the following problem with **shiny** app: a `reactive` object will be created after some procedures. In the middle of the way there is an `actionButton`, which depending on the option, one or another calculation will be made. This object will be used in an `output`. The problem is that when executing the code an error occurs in the output, saying that the function (`reactive`) was not found. This function should be executed only after the object is created. I've tried everything. `observe`, `observeEvent` (with some crazy things) and nothing worked. Below I tried to create a minimal reproducible code that would portray my problem.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput('num','Put a number!',value=1),
  uiOutput("datas")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
 
 observe({
  if(input$num==2){
  num <- reactive({
                  nume <- input$num + 2
                  nume
                  })
  
  showModal(modalDialog(
     title = "Menssagem importante",
     "Escolha uma das opções abaixo",
     footer = tagList(
                      actionButton("sim","Sim"),
                      actionButton("nao","Não")
                      )
      ))
      
   observeEvent(input$sim,{
      newnum <- NULL
      for(i in 1:20){
             newnum[i] <- num()+1
          }
      newnum            
   }) 
   
   observeEvent(input$nao,{
      newnum <- NULL
      for(i in 1:20){
             newnum[i] <- num()+5
          }
      newnum            
   })
   
   resfinal <- reactive({
                        value <- newnum()^2 + log(10)
                        value
                        })
  }          
 })
 
 output$datas <- renderPrint({ resfinal() })
   
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I appreciate if someone gives me some light.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get it correctly but maybe it can be helpful:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput('num', 'Put a number!', value = 1),
  uiOutput("datas")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  num_react <- reactiveVal()
  newnum_react <- reactiveVal()

  observe({
    if(input$num == 2){
      num_react(input$num + 2)
      
      showModal(
        modalDialog(
          title = "Mensagem importante",
          "Escolha uma das opções abaixo",
          footer = tagList(
            actionButton("sim", "Sim"),
            actionButton("nao", "Não")
          )
        )
      )
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$sim, {
    newnum <- numeric(20)
    for(i in 1:20) newnum[i] <- num_react() + 1

    newnum_react(newnum)
    removeModal()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$nao, {
    newnum <- numeric(20)
    for(i in 1:20) newnum[i] <- num_react() + 5

    newnum_react(newnum)
    removeModal()
  })
  
  resfinal <- reactive({
    value <- newnum_react()^2 + log(10)
    value
  })

  output$datas <- renderPrint({
    req(resfinal())
    resfinal() 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The idea is to use `reactiveVal` to store the values you need and then you can use `req()` to avoid the error when the object is not available yet.

Comment: Hi Douglas!Your suggestion is very good and smart. However, I couldn't adapt it to my problem. I tried playing everyone (including `output$object`) but it didn't work. The `output$object` continues to be read, that is, this time the error is like a `NULL`, since the `reactive` still doesn't exist in the same way. So, I still have no solution. The problem with shiny code is that our real code is large and sometimes complex, and minimal reproducible code is not enough. Thanks Douglas.